# Is there any way to manually reset circuit breaker in Micronaut?

Tags: micronaut, circuit-breaker

I am trying to figure out if it is possible manually reset Circuit breakers in Tests (Java). I am currently adding sleep for it to reset itself, but is not ideal as tests will run much longer.

I was thinking to inject `CircuitBreakerRetry` and change state manually, but it is package private so it is not an option.

`Histryx` has a manual reset for the same purpose I was wondering if there is anything in `Micronaut`.

Currently I have it anntoated on the client method:

```
class MyClient {
   @CircuitBreaker(
        delay = "${config.client.circutBreaker.delay}",
        reset = "${config.client.circutBreaker.resetTimeout}",
        attempts = "${config.client.circutBreaker.maxFailures}"
   )
   public Single<JsonNode> callClient() {
     <...>
   }
 }
```

In the test I inject `MyCient` and mock the endpoints using `wiremock`. So if I throw an error or simulate timeout in `Wiremock it opens the circuit and to close I need to wait` resetTimeout`.

Comment: A snippet of what has been done so far would be useful, contoller, endpoint, test class...

Comment: @tmarwen I've added some details. I didn't progress much in the test reseting it as there was no way of accessing mechanisms of the circuit breaker. I can't even inject the CircuitBreakerRetry as it is package private. Otherwise I was thinking to extend it and manage the state manually in the tests. Even if I extend in the pacakges the same as original CircuitBreakerRetry, but then replacing the bean would be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

`@MicronautTest(rebuildContext = true)` should rebuild the injected mock before each test, which will reset the circuit breaker